# How to fetch data along with relationship data in Laravel using with keyword?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I fetch data along with blog category and blog tags from Blogs table using `with` in query.

Below is my model and controller code, I am getting `Get Blogs Api Error` instead of the blogs data.

`Blog Controller`

```
public function getBlogs()
{
    try {
        $blogs = Blog::where('status', 1)
            ->with('category')
            ->with('tag')
            ->with('user')
            ->with('comment')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(5);
        return response()->json($blogs);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        $e = "Get Blogs Api Error";
        return response()->json($e);
    }
}
```

`Blog Model`

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }
    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
    }
    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

`User Model`

```
public function blog_user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Blog::class);
}
```

`Blog Category Model`

```
public function blog_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Blog::class);
}
```

`Blog Tag Model`

```
public function blog_tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Blog::class);
}
```

`Blog Comment Model`

```
public function blog_comment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Blog::class);
}
```

`Database table structure`

`blogs table structure`

[image: Blogs table structure]

`blog_categories table structure`

[image: Blog Category]

`blog_tags table structure`

[image: Blog Tags]

Comment: what is the error log? in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-multiple-relationships) you need to use with([array])

Comment: @Atmahadli catch{} is getting executed, I tried using with[array] also with(['category', 'tag', 'user', 'comment']), but same error

Comment: I see you catch the QueryException, so what is the actual error there?

Comment: @Atmahadli try using plural for comments, categories and tags.

Comment: @r89human sorry, my bad english.

Comment: @Atmahadli no problem. i proposed a solution. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change names to plural. not singular. as you are using one to many. and use belongsToMany() method. not hasMany().

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

and change the name of pivot table to blog_category not blog_categories. It will work. and your BlogCategory model will look like this.

```
class BlogCategory extends Model {
    protected $table = 'blog_category';

    public function blog() {
        return $this->belongsTo( Blog::class );
    }
}
```

now you can get blogs like this.

```
$blogs = Blog::with( 'categories' )->get();
```

and this is how you will fetch blog for any category.

```
$category = BlogCategory::where( 'category_id', $category->id )->first();

dd( $category->blog );
```

Comment: thanks for the update, but my output should not depend on any category, it should be all blogs and along with each blog related data like, comments, tags, category.  I am quering using `with` keyword.

Comment: use this query.   $blogs = Blog::with( 'categories' )->get();